# Magento 2 Migration Tool - Delta Delivering Failed - Deltalog not installed

Tags: magento2-migration-tool

After a successful initial data migration from 1.8.1.0 >> 2.0.2 CE using the Migration Tool NOW getting *"Migration/Exception - Delta delivering failed"* because the *"Deltalog for customer_entity is not installed"*

How can the "Deltalog" be "installed"?

Why is the "Detalog" not installed along with the tool or during the initial migration process?

Why did Delta fail?

If you reset then there is no Delta; True?

Magento2 is 2.0.7. Updated via CL from magento2 2.0.2 >> 2.0.4 >> 2.0.7

Migration Tool Version 2.0.7

[image]

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem?

Comment: Please add "--reset" in the command refer following example:
 /usr/local/bin/php magento migrate:data --reset /home/magento/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.3.3/config.xml

Answer (score 3):

When using the magento migration:data command tables are created with m2_cl_ prefix on source database that is magento 1 database and as you are doing incremental migration with magento:delta which works usually with customer and sales record the problem shows the source database doesn't contain those tables. Which means you have to use the same source database from the moment of the migration or adjust the new database with these tables in it.